# Not receiving WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN on title bar

Tags: c++builder

I am trying to create a mechanism to allow the user to right click and drag on a toolbar in order to move a window...

This is proving very difficult:

I am currently not receiving the HTCAPTION event which I have seen a really helpful post for already!

[Not receiving WM_NCHitTest on title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631831/not-receiving-wm-nchittest-on-title-bar)

The suggestion/alternative here is to use the WMNCMouseMove and inspect the HitTest to see if it is the caption.. So naively I assumed that I could extend this idea to use the WMNCMButtonDown (instead) to take me one step closer!

If this worked then I could get the type of click i.e. left, right, middle, double or single! This would have then allow me to somehow tell windows that I want this to be recognised as a drag event.

The trouble is that I never receive the WM_NCMBUTTONDOW:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Dispatch( void* message )
{
    switch ( static_cast<TMessage*>( message )->Msg )
    {

        case WM_NCHITTEST:
        {

            TWMNCHitTest &Message = *static_cast<TWMNCHitTest*>( message );
            WMNCHitTest( Message );
            break;
        }

        case WM_NCMOUSEMOVE:
        {
            TWMNCMouseMove &Message = *static_cast<TWMNCMouseMove*>( message );
            WMNCMouseMove( Message );
            break;
        }
       case WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN:
       {
           TWMNCMButtonDown &Message = *static_cast<TWMNCMouseMove*>( message );
           WMNCMButtonDown(Message);
           break;
       }
       default:
       {
           TForm::Dispatch(message);
           break;
       }

    }  
}
```

oes anybody have any ideas??

It is worth noting that I do in fact receive the other types of messages (WM_NCHITTEST && WM_NCMOUSEMOVE) so the mechanism is working correctly.

Please any ideas would be much appreciated!!

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: You should be overriding the `WndProc()` method instead of the `Dispatch()` method.

Comment: Even if I add this to the WndProc function it still never hits my breakpoint i.e. I am never getting the WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN. I do get the WM_NCMOUSEMOVE amongst other messages?

Comment: According to the MSDN documentation: "If a window has captured the mouse, this message is not posted."  Is the mouse being captured at the time you are expecting the message?  What is the return value of `GetCapture()`?

Answer (score 0):

I do the following rather than override any methods.

In my .h

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
{
   VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER( WM_NCHITTEST, TWMNCHitTest, WMNCHitTest );
   VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER( WM_NCCALCSIZE, TWMNCCalcSize, WMNCCalcSize );
   VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER( WM_NCPAINT, TWMNCPaint, WMNCPaint );
   VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER( WM_ERASEBKGND, TWMEraseBkgnd, StopFlicker );
   VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER( WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, TWMNCLButtonDown, WMNCLButtonDown );
}
END_MESSAGE_MAP( TCustomPanel )  // change TCustomPanel to your parent class name

void __fastcall WMNCHitTest( Messages::TWMNCHitTest& inoutMessage );
void __fastcall WMNCCalcSize( Messages::TWMNCCalcSize& inoutMessage );
void __fastcall WMNCPaint( Messages::TWMNCPaint& inoutMessage );
void __fastcall StopFlicker( Messages::TWMEraseBkgnd& inoutMessage );
void __fastcall WMNCLButtonDown( Messages::TWMNCLButtonDown& inoutMessage );
```

And then I implement the code in the .cpp, for example:

```
void __fastcall TResizePanel::WMNCLButtonDown( Messages::TWMNCLButtonDown &inoutMessage )
{
   if ( inoutMessage.HitTest == HTCLOSE )
   {
      delete this;
      inoutMessage.Result = 0;
   }
   else
   {
      Dispatch( &inoutMessage );
   }
}
```

Comment: A `MESSAGE_MAP` is a fancy override of the `Dispatch()` method. As such, you should be calling the inherited `Dispatch()` method instead of calling `DefaultHandler()` directly.

Comment: @remy Hmm, ok.  This is working quite well, but probably because I am using a TPanel which does not have many (any?) custom message handling.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry for the late reply. I have sorted the problem now. I am simply artificially moving the form using the NC right mouse button down, NC mouse move and also a Timer as the mouse move is not quick enough. Thanks for your advice though.